# Split using perl when tab is the delimiter between columns

Tags: perl

Suppose the data is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
a a s d f c
z s    g qq
```

I wrote the following script in Perl to split data columnwise:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use Text::CSV;

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line"; 
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
 chomp $line;
 my @fields = split " " , $line;
 print "$fields[2]\n";
}
```

when I run the command, I get the following output

```
3
s
g
```

when I should be getting the output as:

```
3
s
```

there should be a blank space in 3rd row. The script shifts the values of other column to fill the blank column.

Comment: Split on tab, not space char.

Comment: i made the changes

#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get CSV file on the command line";
open(my $data, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split("\t") , $line;
  print "$fields[1]\n";
}
but i am getting error
Useless use of private variable in void context at csv1.pl line 10.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in split at csv1.pl line 10, <$data> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 11, <$data> line 1.

Comment: That's because it's `split( "\t", $line)` not what you've written.

Comment: You are getting error _Useless use of private variable in void context_ because you have written `\t` in parenthesis. This `my @fields = split("\t") , $line;` should be this `my @fields = split("\t", $line);`

Comment: i did that change, it still giving me an eror 

Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 13, <$data> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 13, <$data> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 13, <$data> line 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiter is tab, so use tab `\t` to split instead of space:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $data, '<', "file.txt" or die "Could not open file: $!";
while (my $line = <$data>)
{
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split ("\t", $line);
    print "$fields[2]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
3
s
```

Note: There is a blank line after 's' in output (i.e. 3rd line).

Comment: i am trying to run the script, with print "$fields[0]\n";  it gives me the complete file.. when i changed to print "$fields[1]\n";  or any other value in index, i get the following error     

Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 23, <$data> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 23, <$data> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $fields[1] in concatenation (.) or string at csv1.pl line 23, <$data> line 3.

Comment: Above script is for you given input data. Did you try this with given data?

Comment: And _Use of uninitialized value_ is not an error, its warning that for the particular index value is undefined in the input file.

Comment: yes i am trying with the same data. I am passing the file name as a command line parameter, on using index 0 it outputs the whole file(just like cat will do ), but when i give any other index, it gives me the error as above. I did the change my @fields = split("\t",$line);

Comment: ok a warning, because it did not find anything to display for indexes higher than 0, but it should not be the case. I copied your whole code i.e. gave the filename in the script itself, but i am still getting the error.

Comment: If you try the same data, it must be work, even if you pass the file name from the command line. Just check your input file, that all values are separated with tab, not with space.

Comment: I did a mistake by writing the file in a text editor and copying it to the command prompt.This time, I created file in the unix terminal itself, it worked. Thanks :):)

Answer (score 4):

`split ' '` is a special split feature that works like `split /\s+/` (except that leading empty fields are discarded).  Since you want to split on *each*  tab, not on groups of one or more whitespace characters, you should do so with `split /\t/`.